# fazer um redirect de um sub-dominio para dominio principal

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewrite

Olá preciso fazer um redirect de um blog ativo instalado no sub-dominio para o dominio principal montei um redirect do sub para o principal, o problema são os POSTs deste blog que já estão indexados quero redirecionar todas URLs na web para a default do dominio principal.

Redirect do sub para o principal funciona mas as urls dos posts retorna Not found

```
    <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="BlogToPrincipal" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^blog\.meudominio\.com\.br$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.meudominio.com.br/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Qual seria um "URL dos posts"?

Comment: Na verdade quero redirecionar tudo que esta indexado na internet deste blog, ou seja o que aparececer de blog.meudominio.com.br para meudominio.com.br, do jeito que fiz só redireciona  até o ".br " o que estiver ddepois do ".br/qualquercoisa" me retorna Page Not Found 404